# s3.getSignedUrl ResponseContentDisposition parameter not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers

I'm successfully generating a signed url that I can then use for a limited time to download resources from my s3 bucket.  However I'm trying to use the ResponseContentDisposition attribute in the params as documented here:

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong but for some reason the headers are not being set.  For example if I use the url I get back from s3.getSignedUrl:

`curl -i "https://foo-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/images/foo.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAICBHUC26S6B446PQ&Expires=1468359314&Signature=EeBqx1G83oeusarBl2KUbbCCBgA%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Ddata.jpg"`

the headers are:

```
x-amz-id-2: SG9rjYQCcuqgKfjBmMbDQC2CNLcnqBAFzP7zINa99VYUwNijPOm5Ea/5fllZ6cnt/Qti7e26hbE=
x-amz-request-id: 2670068008525B1D
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 21:26:16 GMT
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=foo.jpg
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 00:47:23 GMT
ETag: "2a8e36651b24769170f4faa429f40f54"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 43373
Server: AmazonS3
```

I'm setting this, using the javascript s3 sdk like this:

```
function tempRedirect(req, res) {
    var filename = req.params[0];
    var contentDisposition = 'attachment; filename=data.jpg';
    var params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        ResponseContentDisposition: contentDisposition,
        Key: checkTrailingSlash(getFileKeyDir(req)) + filename
    };
    var s3 = new aws.S3(s3Options);
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function(err, url) {
        res.redirect(url);
    });
};
```

The docs are pretty light and I can only find PHP examples but it does look like I'm setting content disposition correctly.

Anyone know what is going wrong here??

Comment: You shouldn't need to use ResponseContentDisposition. Make sure you're passing the `putObject` method a content-type argument (e.g., would be something like `contentType: 'image/jpeg'`) when initially putting the file in your S3 bucket. Then when you download them via a presigned URL, the object already contains the necessary metadata to handle it as a JPG attachment; this means that when you attempt to download the object via presigned URL, it knows to automatically open a file picker asking you where you want to save the appropriately-typed attachment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [RFC- 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), your value is malformed.

The expected format is `attachment; filename="funny-cat.jpg"`.  The filename is a quoted string.

And, my original assumption was that S3 was rejecting it as invalid and silently refusing to replace the value.

Subsequent tests reveal unexpected behavior:  if `Content-Disposition` is not stored with the object, then `&response-content-disposition=...` works as expected, setting the response header.  But if there is a header stored with the object, this query string parameter does not have the documented effect of "overriding" that value.

Conversely, `&response-content-type=...` *does* override a stored `Content-Type:` for the object.

That's what a few quick tests revealed for me.

But this appears to be a bug -- or more accurately, some kind of regression -- in S3.  According to one support forum post, the behavior is actually inconsistent, sometimes working and sometimes not.

> S3 is aware of this issue and we are working to resolve it. (2016-07-12)
>
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235006

Comment: I've tried quoted and unquoted.  Still S3 always serves with original Content-disposition and ignores my ReponseContentDisposition parameter.  Am I just calling it totally wrong somehow?  Or possibly am I misunderstanding how this parameter is supposed to change the headers in the actual download?

Comment: Really I should be able to set contentDisposition to "foo bar bar" and I'd expect, although it is totally wrong, for S3 to just reflect that value back to me.  If they are doing some validation on my setting and ignoring it because it is malformed, getObject and getSignedUrl don't let me know that in any way and should probably just fail outright.

Comment: Agreed, a silent failure is unexpected but it was the only possibility thst came to mind, because what you are trying should do exactly what you intend.  It allows you to set the response header on a download, overriding the header stored with the object.

Comment: Ah.  Found it.  See the updated answer.  Also, you're right, it's not validated.

Comment: Michael, thank you!  Looks like we just have to wait!

Comment: I've found that if you generate the resigned URL via the web console it won't include the correct Content-Disposition header in the response but if you use the CLI or an SDK it will.